# spring data rest with CrudRepository with @Embeddable

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I got the following simplified entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class SalesProcess {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    private Date nextContactDate;

    private String nextContactNote;

    @Embedded
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private ActualProduct actualProduct;

    private SalesProcess() {}
}


@Data
@Embeddable
public class ActualProduct {

    private String type;
    private Date manufactureDate;

    private ActualProduct() {}
}
```

This way i do have the data a bit separated though still everything in one table.

To get the REST endpoint i create a simple Interface extending from CrudRepository:

```
public interface SalesProcessRepository extends CrudRepository<SalesProcess, Long> {}
```

When i do a get request to `http://localhost:8080/salesProcesses/1' i do get the correct response with the embedded type included like that:

```
{
  ...
  actualProduct: {
    type: 'some type',
    ...
  },
}
```

My **Problem** is when i try to create a new `SalesProcess` by executing a `POST` request to the server with my `actualProduct` embedded like i do get at the `GET` response, every column from the embedded type is null in the database. The rest endpoint returns 200.

**Funfact**

I tried to write a custom controller and stored the `SalesProcess` with the `SalesProcessRepository`. Tested it with the same query and it works. I dont know why the spring-data-rest generated rest endpoint does not store the embedded type :(